# Text file to useable text by TextView via class - Android

Tags: android, textview, fileinputstream

I have a text file in `res/raw/stringtest.txt`. On each line of this there are different lines of text that need to be put into individual `TextViews`.

Where can I find the java code to read the text file and then put it into textViews?

I believe you can use a `FileInputStream` to output the text to the Logcat but that is as far as I know so far. I know you put some code into the class files but I am unsure what it is to make it place the Text into the TextViews by id. Any information or code will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a [`BufferedReader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader.html), for its `readLine` method. Something like:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.id.my_raw_file)));
        String line = null;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // update TextView with string
        }
```